# Could women make contracts in ancient Rome?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, law

I'm writing a story and the main character is a wealthy widow who runs the estate for her rather lazy son. Could women in ancient Rome (specifically the 3rd Century Empire) legally make contracts, or could only men?

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. Can you explain why the relevant Wikipedia pages and google searches didn't answer the question?  [SE sites work best if the questions are supported by preliminary research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2085030)

Comment: Have you looked at [Women in Ancient Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_ancient_Rome#In_business)? If this doesn't answer your question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: @LarsBosteen thanks for the feedback. I've been to that page before but I must've overlooked or forgotten the business section for some reason. I feel kinda stupid now. I guess you hear so much about the oppressed state of women in ancient Rome that you forget the freedoms they did have. Thanks again

Comment: I recommend you read _[Household Gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Household_Gods)_ by Harry Turtledove.